# APC crashes when user cache is used

Tags: php, crash, apc

I'm developing a PHP app and and want to cache some data in APC. APC is running and enabled, I can see statistics when I open apc.php which indicate that opcode caching works fine.

However, the apache process crashes whenever I try to use `apc_store()` or `apc_add()` to store some data.

This is on a Windows 7 Professional 64bit system and happens with both of these version combinations:

- Apache 2.2.21, PHP 5.3.9, APC 3.1.6
- Apache 2.2.22, PHP 5.3.13, APC 3.1.9

With the first configuration, the crash happens immediately and this in the apache error log:

```
[Fri Jun 08 12:51:58 2012] [notice] Parent: child process exited with status 255 -- Restarting.
```

With second there is some delay and I get this:

```
[Fri Jun 08 16:18:48 2012] [notice] Child 5052: Exit event signaled. Child process is ending.
[Fri Jun 08 16:18:48 2012] [warn] (OS 995)Der E/A-Vorgang wurde wegen eines Threadendes oder einer Anwendungsanforderung abgebrochen.  : winnt_accept: Asynchronous AcceptEx failed.
[Fri Jun 08 16:18:48 2012] [warn] (OS 10038)Ein Vorgang bezog sich auf ein Objekt, das kein Socket ist.  : setsockopt(SO_UPDATE_ACCEPT_CONTEXT) failed.
[Fri Jun 08 16:18:52 2012] [warn] pid file C:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.2.22/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
[Fri Jun 08 16:18:52 2012] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Win64) PHP/5.3.13 configured -- resuming normal operations
```

What can be done to fix this?

Comment: Have you tried getting apache to do a core dump when it crashes? Also nothing in the error logs?

Comment: @patyx7: I added information about the error log. I also get a Windows popup about sending information to Microsoft, which mentions three files, one of which has a name like WER2232.tmp.mdmp - is that the core dump? And what would I do with it, not being a C developer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the array I wanted to store contained a native resource, and that caused the crash.

Using `serialize()` before storing it and `unserialize()` afterwards fixed the problem.